# Deploy Office 365 Word Add-in to Azure (error: command lsof not found)

Tags: azure, docker, office-addins, yeoman-generator

I'm trying to host a bare-bones version of a Word add-in based on the Yeoman add-in generator to see if I can get the deployment to other users with a public manifest.xml file.

I can succesfully sideload and launch the app locally.

However, when I attempt to deploy the code through Git to the Azure machine, the machine fails with the following:

**NPM logs:**

```
Unable to start the dev server. Error: Command failed: lsof -n -i:3000
bin/sh: 1: lsof: not found
```

**Docker logs**

```
Container ***** didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging
```

It appears to be NPM deploying at port 3000, whereas Docker is expecting port 8080 to be listened to. I've updated all the settings in the repository to 8080 (I think), but somehow the Docker still seems to fail. Any ideas?

Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out the port-config was in the `package.json` where I wasn't able to find it at first. Getting rid of the wrong port setting there got me into a different sequence of errors, most pertaining to other stuff that wouldn't run in the Unix environment (such as the devCerts plugin that enabled https).

The final solution I used for this test scenario was to deploy using the template provided by Visual studio in the Azure setup. Starting from the Word-addin template I was able to add in the existing code and succesfully deploy to an Azure server to test the plugin.